# Convert View Pane Display to a Block Display

Tags: views

I have a view with a pane display. However, for the page I want to place it on, it turns out that I need a block display instead of a pane.

How do clone or convert a pane display to a block display?

It's not the master display, so creating a new block doesn't inherit the settings I want.

Comment: I am sure you would have been  aware of this. Just to point out. Why are you not using mini-panel, It will provide the panel functionality and will output it as a block.

Comment: @CodeNext not sure what you mean-- the display is 'Content Pane'. I don't find that name or the name of the view on my blocks page. The target page where I want to place this display is not under panelizer nor a panel page.

Comment: If I understood correctly. You have panel page. You can convert that Panel to Mini-panel and Mini-panels are blocks. Hence, you will get the Panel in the form of Block. I am providing the link, may help. http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/97863/can-a-panel-be-converted-to-a-mini-panel

Comment: @CodeNext I don't have a Panel page. I thought I did, which is why I made a pane display. But I don't, so I need a block display.

Comment: Oh, I got you, you have pane display, right, my bad.

Comment: @CodeNext sorry I wasn't more clear originally; thanks for sticking with me : )

Comment: D7 solution https://www.drupal.org/project/views/issues/1208282#comment-12546316